# ClaimsAuthorizationManager issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, wif

I am using a custom **ClaimsAuthorizationManager** to do Authorization in MVC, but I am running into an issue.

- Even if I simply return 'true' in the CheckAccess method, all
  files/images are being blocked with a 500 run-time error because:

> Exception information: 
>       Exception type: NotSupportedException 
>       Exception message: ID1075: The ClaimsAuthorizationModule cannot be used without the current principal (HttpContext.Current.User) being a
>   ClaimsPrincipal.    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.ClaimsAuthorizationModule.Authorize()

I am not changing anything regarding the Current Principal earlier in the application...  Thoughts?  I am stumped and searching for that error reveals nothing...

---

```
<system.webServer>    
    <modules>      
      ...
      <add name="ClaimsAuthorizationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.ClaimsAuthorizationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>


  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <claimsAuthorizationManager type="NamespaceFun.CustomAuthorizationManager, NamespaceFun" >
    <policy resource="http://localhost:52606/" action="GET">
    </policy>
      </claimsAuthorizationManager>
      ...
    </identityConfiguration>
   </system.identityModel>


public class CustomAuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
{      
    public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
    {   
        return true;            
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It figures I would ask a question and then answer it myself an hour later.  But this had me perplexed for multiple days.  It wasn't until it was actually blocking me from getting other stuff done that I had to dig into it.

So anyway, what I did was pretty simple.  This example of the **ClaimsAuthorizationManager** from Microsoft does *Not* have any issues serving up Images.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Claims-Aware-MVC-523e079b

So I compared the Web.config files from both applications and found out they were 'amazingly' similar.

The only difference is that my intranet application had these handlers in the system.webServer section:

```
 <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
```

I actually need to figure out what these are doing, but at the moment, removing them solves my original issue.

WIF is still a giant 'black box' in my opinion.  Its hard to adopt a new technology when Googling for errors returns absolutely nothing.

Comment: Here we are in 2015, and still not much has changed in this regard.

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem, so I compared my web.config to one in the WIF book, and it turns out I was missing `preCondition="managedHandler"` from the end of the add element, and it seems you're missing it too.

It also seems to be missing from the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthorizationmanager.aspx).

Correct way:

```
<add name="ClaimsAuthorizationModule" 
     type="System.IdentityModel.Services.ClaimsAuthorizationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
     preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually think it is a really bad idea to use the claims authorization module at all. The reason is that the module is based off URLs - but in MVC everything is keyed off the routing table or controllers/actions.

Whenever the two get out of sync you might have holes in your authorization policy (plus the issue with static files that you already encountered). I actually prefer the attribute based approach - I built to authorize attributes (one for MVC, one for Web API) that play nice with ASP.NET:

http://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/26/using-claims-based-authorization-in-mvc-and-web-api/

Comment: how do you handle dynamic roles coming from the database?  Everything is either pointing towards Attributes or ClaimsAuthorizationManager, and at least with the CAM, I don't have to worry about missing an attribute on a controller somewhere and have one central location to do authorization.

I agree its not great though, and I can't even redirect, I just fail, which then prompts the user with another login box I have yet to eliminate so far...

Comment: Well you can add the ClaimsAuthorize filter as a global filter - then it will be called for every request (regardless of the attribute). It will then pass the controller/action names to the authorization manager. There's a reason Microsoft added the attributes, because maintaining things in two places leads to errors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason why files (including JavaScript) were being blocked when using custom ClaimsAuthorizationManager was because of the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` attribute in modules tag:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

This results in processing all requests by the custom ClaimsAuthorizationManager [even if the request was not for managed content](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/modules). **Removing** that attribute solves the issue.